# NLog File splitting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nlog

I'm using NLog to log to file. Is there a way to configure it to create a new log file when the current one reaches a certain threshold (eg ~50mb)? Can it be done from the configuration file or code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Yes](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/File_target#Size-based_file_archival):

```
fileName="${basedir}/logs/logfile.txt" 
archiveFileName="${basedir}/archives/log.{#####}.txt"
archiveAboveSize="5242880"
archiveNumbering="Sequence"
concurrentWrites="true" <!-- http://nlog-project.org/doc/2.0/sl2/html/P_NLog_Targets_FileTarget_ArchiveAboveSize.htm -->
```